# Simple template matching with python-openCv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I am trying to detect some simple 'red patterns' in an image. Here is the algorithm I follow: 
1) filter out all other colors rather than 'red' and creating a balck&white image. I used 'cvtColor' with appropriate masking then I applied 'GaussianBlur' to reduce the noise. So far everthing is fine.

2) I used function 'matchTemplate' as follows to detect the 'arrow' templete  in image.

**Problem**: when 'arrow' template is in photo , it is detected correctly. 
But when it is not in photo, algorithm detect some other shapes which is mistake.
Can somebody modify code, so that when arrow template is not in picture, nothing get detected. 
Here is my code:

```
    template = cv2.imread(address,0)
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(self.image['blured'], template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    cv2.rectangle(self.image['blured'],top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
    cv2.rectangle(self.image['normal'], top_left, bottom_right, 255,2)
```

Here are the results: 
[image: Correctly detected]

[image]

Wrong detections:
[image: circle is detected as arrow]

[image]

My template image , which I cropped exactly from main photo:

[image]

Anybody can detect my mistake? I am new in image processing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at your `max_val` and put a threshold on it.

Let's say `max_val` is `x1` when the image contains the arrow and is `x2` when the image does not contain the arrow, it should be that `x1 > x2`. As a first tentative value you can choose `threshold=(x1+x2)/2` and then if `max_val > threshold` then the pattern is found in the image else the pattern is not found.

The reason is that [`matchTemplate`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be)

> slides through `image` , compares the overlapped patches of size `w`
>   \times `h`against `templ` using the specified method and stores the
>   comparison results in `result`.

and so your image `res` will always have a maximum value disregarding the presence of the arrow in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Alessandro Jacopson. 
I modified the code and solved the problem in this way. It is almost what you proposed:

```
        template = cv2.imread(address,0)
        w, h = template.shape[::-1]
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(self.image['blured'], template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        threshold = 0.9
        loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
           cv2.rectangle(self.image['blured'], pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
           cv2.rectangle(self.image['normal'], pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
```

In this way patterns are detected quite accurate. 
**New problem:** It is sensitive about direction and rotation. It doesn't detect the pattern if it is rotated.for example around 45 degree. 
Is there any parameter I can set, and make the algorithm to find the pattern, although it is rotated or scaled?

Comment: For the **New problem** you should ask a new question... Anyway I think it will be a duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666436/scale-and-rotation-template-matching and so please, before asking a new questions, read that answers.